# Contact form 7 not sending emails to admin or user

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email, contact-form

I am running Contact Form 4.1.2 on Wordpress 4.2. Once a user has submitted their contact form on any of the forms being used on the site, no emails come through to the designated email addresses on the back-end of the site. [Here](http://northwestplumbingandheating.co.uk) is the site I am working on, and [here](http://northwestplumbingandheating.co.uk/contact-us/) is one of the contact forms I am referring too.

I have also tried using Ninja Forms as a substitute but that's also not working, I am aware that this means it's not strictly to do with Contact Form 7, but can't pin what else it could be.

Anything else you may need let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: If no emails are sending, that alludes to an issue with your server or SMTP client being able to send mail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would I go about solving this? Would I need to contact my host? If so, what should I ask them to do? I know my hosting provider personally as they use a re seller account, so I want to ensure I say the right thing to make sure this gets fixed ASAP.

Comment: If you're comfortable with PHP, you could add a file to test the `wp_mail()` function directly, as well as the PHP `mail()` function. If you try to invoke these directly, and they fail, you should learn a little more about the issue. It's not really possible to troubleshoot from here without knowing your server configuration.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your reply once again. Is there any information that I could provide you with regarding the server configuration that I could possibly get from my hosting provider?

Comment: Both of those functions require the settings `SMTP` and `smtp_port` to be set in your *php.ini* file. I'd start there and ask if both have been enabled in your server's PHP configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mevius. I really appreciate the support.